# Issues with 11.10 display resolution

Tags: resolution, xrandr

I want to increase the resolution of my Acer Aspire One D250-1326 which has Ubuntu 11.10 installed. The native resolution is 1024x600 and I want to increase it to 1440x810 or 135%. I've tried two methods that both use xrandr...creating a new resolution mode and applying it to my display, and scaling the display.

This picture shows the commands I entered into the terminal to create a new resolution mode:

[image]

1. Enter "xrandr -q" to show that the current resolution is 1024x600.
2. Enter "cvt 1440 810 60" to find the modeline for a resolution of 1440x810 at 60Hz.
3. Enter "xrandr --newmode..." to create the custom mode.
4. Enter "xrandr --addmode LVDS1..." to apply the mode to my netbook display. Here is where I experience the "BadMatch" error.
   Note: When I enter "xrandr --addmode VGA1..." instead, the mode is successfully applied to the VGA1 display.

The second method I attempted is scaling the display. I had success using this method when I used Ubuntu 11.04. Now for some reason, when I use the same scaling command, my mouse becomes constrained to the top-left portion of the screen. Here are the steps I took:

[image]

1. Enter "xrandr -q" to show the current state of the display.
   Note: You can see the mode I created during the previous method. Again, I was not able to apply it to the LVDS1 display, but I could apply it to VGA1.
2. Enter "xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1.35x1.35" to scale the display. After this is done, the resolution is changed but the mouse cannot move any lower than you see here in the picture.

I also tried using different panning options without any success. One route I did see is to revert a patch which is said to solve the scaling problem. I have not been able to figure out how to perform this action though. Here is a link, with the confirmation near the bottom:
BUGS(dot)freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39949  (Dang spam prevention, can't post >2 links)

I would appreciate your help solving this problem. Otherwise I guess I'll just go back to 11.04. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I Also have a Netbook with a native 1024x600 resolution which is too small sometimes.
I struggled hard with xrandr and searched a lot in www and so on.
Finally, I got a Solution which works for my EeePc.
I Use a trick: I configure a not-connected VGA-Output, that helped increase the resolution
without the mouse been catched.
This Example shows a scaling by 1.5:

xrandr --newmode "1536x900" 113.75  1536 1624 1784 2032  900 903 913 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1536x900
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1536x900 --output LVDS1 --fb 1536x900 --scale 1.5x1.5

I hope it works for you too !

Oliver

Answer (score 1):

```
xrandr --newmode "1536x900" 113.75  1536 1624 1784 2032  900 903 913 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1536x900
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1536x900 --output LVDS1 --fb 1536x900 --scale 1.5x1.5
```